# how to filter out some substrings with regex effectively?

Tags: java, regex

i want to filter out srcport and dstport from the input string. here is the code i tried:

```
String input = "2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,devname=B3909601569,devid=B3909601569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.123,srcport=2072,srcintf=port2,dstip=10.180.1.105,dstport=3206,dstintf=port1,sessionid=121543,status=close,policyid=196,service=MYSQL,proto=6,duration=10,sentbyte=3910,rcvdbyte=175085,sentpkt=74,rcvdpkt=132";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(srcport=)(\\d+).[\\s]?(dstport=)(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {

System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(2) + " & ");
System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(4));

}

System.out.println(result);
```

but its not showing any output. Is there a mistake in the regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(srcport=)(\\d+).[\\s]?(dstport=)(\\d+)");
```

or the println lines

```
System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(2) + " & ");
System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(4));"
```

any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do a proper formatting the question

Comment: I would use a [`MapSplitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html) for that (using ',' and '=')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See following changes to both the regex and the captured groups:

```
    String input = "2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,devname=B3909601569,devid=B3909601569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.123,srcport=2072,srcintf=port2,dstip=10.180.1.105,dstport=3206,dstintf=port1,sessionid=121543,status=close,policyid=196,service=MYSQL,proto=6,duration=10,sentbyte=3910,rcvdbyte=175085,sentpkt=74,rcvdpkt=132";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("srcport=(\\d+).*?dstport=(\\d+)"); // update regex
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(1)); //print groups 1 + 2
        System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(2));

    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: one more doubt.This might be silly, but i am new to these. In case, if a few lines are there as input. then what change shall i make?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use  or(`|`) in your regex

```
srcport=(\\d+)|dstport=(\\d+)
```

Your code would be

```
while (m.find()) 
{
    if(m.group().startsWith("srcport"))
        System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(1) + " & ");
    else
        System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(1));

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but while using it your way Iam getting an output as: Srcport: 2072 & 
Dstport: 2072
Srcport: null & 
Dstport: null

Comment: @Neelutpol check out the code in the answer above..You need to check if it startswith srcport

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("srcport=(\\d+)|dstport=(\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. I have run this in my system and it it working fine.

String input = "2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,devname=B3909601569,devid=B3909601569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.123,srcport=2072,srcintf=port2,dstip=10.180.1.105,dstport=3206,dstintf=port1,sessionid=121543,status=close,policyid=196,service=MYSQL,proto=6,duration=10,sentbyte=3910,rcvdbyte=175085,sentpkt=74,rcvdpkt=132";

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(srcport=)(\\d+)((.*)?)(dstport=)(\\d+)(\\.)*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        System.out.println("Srcport: " + m.group(2) );
        System.out.println("Dstport: " + m.group(6));

    }
```